# Howto Extjs Resizeable column

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to make the columns resizable. I want to able to drag and extend the column width if needed.

Currently my column are not resizable

Thanks

```
var listView = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: mystore,
    multiSelect: true,
    title: 'Notifications for ' + jsonServiceId + ' <i>(0 items selected)</i>',
    viewConfig: {
        emptyText: 'No images to display'
    },
    //reserveScrollOffset: true,
    renderTo: containerEl,
    layout: 'fit',

    columns: [{
        text: 'Sell',
        flex: 10,
        dataIndex: 'Sell',
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
            //  alert(record.get('Sell'));


        }
    }, {
        text: 'Class',
        flex: 10,
        dataIndex: 'ClassName'
    },


    {
        text: 'Last Changed',
        flex: 20,
        dataIndex: 'LastChangedAt',
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        format: 'd-M-Y h:i a'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default columns are resizable just the way you describe. You can disable resizing by setting `resizable: false` in column definition.

See docs for [`Ext.grid.column.Column`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column)

Comment: fyi, I think you have a spelling mistake, it should be: resizable